# Joomla component + forcedownload

Tags: php, joomla

i have coded a component (Gallery). And i want to intergrate forcedownload for all items.
But will not work :(, just getting corrupted files. I have tried to use exact same code and run it outside of joomla and its works fine. I have created a template thats totaly empty just 
have  but its not help.

My (com_component/views/forcedownload/tmpl/default.php)

```
<?php 
if(!isset($_GET["id"]) || empty($this->item)) {
    echo "Invalid request";
    die();
}

$path       = "images/randomtest/catid".$this->item->cat_id."/";
$filename   = $path.$this->item->filename;
$file = $this->item->filename;

if(!file_exists($filename)) {
    echo "Error: File not found";
    die();
}

header("Cache-Control: public");
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$file");
header("Content-Type: Content-type: application/octet-stream");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
header("Content-Length: ".filesize($filename));
readfile($filename);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is: Are you using `$_GET['format'] = raw`? If not in your controller do

```
if(!isset($_GET["format"]) || $_GET["format"]!='raw') {
    $this->setRedirect( JURI::current(). '?format=raw' );
    return false;
}
```

also in your header you are declared content type as: application/octet-stream, are you sure you want this?

also here:

```
$path       = "images/randomtest/catid".$this->item->cat_id."/";
```

you need, whole SYSTEM PATH not only local one, try using:

```
$path       = JPATH_SITE."/images/randomtest/catid".$this->item->cat_id."/";
```